# How To Refactor 10000 lines of code in Angular js Controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How To Refactor 10000 lines of code in Angular js Controller ? Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Sure thing. Delete files and begin again with React.

Comment: Do you have unit test?

Comment: @raven if they have a 10k loc controller I imagine testing was not on their list of priorities.  Start over, if possible.

Comment: @reven- Nop, No unit test.

Comment: common guys, may be 9500 lines are comments. then its simple as a cake

Comment: @Petr Averyanov - Nop, they are not comments :P

Comment: Try using some duplicated code finder, like [Simian](https://www.harukizaemon.com/simian/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big challenge... 
Some ideas:

- extract some logic in small services, and create unit tests for these services
- create directives for the different parts of the html view (dont isolate scopes, as a first step)
- don't make one big refactoring, start with easy parts, and iterate (small steps)
- be sure that everything is still working after each step
- be patient... One day you'll have 9900 lines only, and then try to have 9800!